# intersection of convex surfaces

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

Given two functions $z=f_1(x,y)$ and $z=f_2(x,y)$, both smooth at least to 2nd order, and let $g(x,y)=0$ be the curve of their intersection projected to the $z=0$ coordinate plane. That is if $f_1(x,y)=f_2(x,y)$ then $g(x,y)=0$. Assume that both $f_1$ and $f_2$ are convex "from below" and their Hessians are positive definite, that is the second variation is positive $\delta^2f_1 >0$ and $\delta ^2f_2 >0$.

Is it true then that the second variation of the intersection curve represented by $g(x,y)$ is not zero, $\delta^2g \ne 0$, in other words it has no inflexion point on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is negative. Have a look at the intersection of those two subsets of almost cylinders. I used almost cylinders to avoid having $\delta^2 f = 0$.

Perspective view:

[image]

and top view, in order to have the intersection curve in $z=0$ plane.

[image]

Comment: Very interesting, what condition on the surfaces is missing to make it so that $\delta^2g>0$ hold (the question is not frivolous, the surfaces to represent chemical potentials and the intersection the phase coexistence curve).

Comment: @hyportnex I don't have an idea about this question. Probably very restrictive conditions as the example I provided seems mundane.

Comment: thank you, I for one have not seen a single real example of a phase coexistence curve that has an inflexion point, my question originated here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/764357/inflection-point-on-a-p-t-phase-transition-coexistence-curve

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again but either appearances are misleading or I do not know what is shown in your example. Write $z=f_1=\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$ and $z=f_2=\sqrt{b^2-y^2}$, then $g(x,y)=a^2-x^2-b^2+y^2=0$, which is a hyperbola when $a \ne b$ or a pair of straight lines $a=b$, neither has an inflection point although for the lines $\delta^2 g \equiv 0$ which I forgot to exclude by saying that I am looking for the existence of isolated inflection points...

Comment: But I think I found part of the answer, and is simpler than I thought; $f_1=f_2$, differentiate twice wrt $x$ and look for $y''=0$. Then: $z_1'=f_{1x}+f_{1y}y'$ and $z_1''=f_{1xx}+2f_{1xy}y'+f_{1yy}y'^2+f_{1y}y''$, now it equal to $z_2''=f_{2xx}+2f_{2xy}y'+f_{2yy}y'^2+f_{2y}y''$ and solve it for $y'$ while setting $y''=0$; there is no real solution of the quadratic if $(f_{1xy}−f_{2xy})^2<(f_{1xx}−f_{2xx})(f_{1yy}−f_{2yy})$. So this is a sufficient condition to guarantee that the intersection curve has no (isolated) inflexion point.

Comment: Since the result is symmetrical it would give the same by differentiating wrt y. I think this is the easier part, the necessary is the more difficult one.

Comment: In your equations, you supposed that the cylinders have coplanar axis, which is not the case in my example. And side topic, you made an error the raising to square. This intersection is surely not an hyperbola… that is unbounded.